# Packing python executable for Windows 7 (64bits)

Tags: python, windows-7, executable

I created a simple Python GUI (tkinter) program on Ubuntu and now I need to prepare an executable to run it on Windows 7. I tried to do that with Nuitka:

```
nuitka --recurse-all --standalone Menu.py
```

On Windows it didn't run. Am I doing sth wrong? Is it better to try other programs instead of Nuitka?

Edit: when I try to run it, Windows shows a dialog box with something like "this version of the program is not good for this Windows. Check if you are using 32 or 64 bits and contact the programmer."

Edit: I decided to do everything from Window using *pyinstaller* and it worked.

Comment: You say it didn't run. What happens when you try to run it? Does it print any error messages? What do they say? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be using py2exe it is quite user friendly.

Download py2exe [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/) and follow the simple installer.

Open your python command line and try `import py2exe` as long as this works the installation is successful.

Don't forget to add the Python folder to your environment variables you can find a simple tutorial on environment variables [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Let's now go through a simple example.

```
#hello.py
print "Hello World!"

python hello.py
Hello World!

#setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe 
setup(console=['hello.py'])

python setup.py install
python setup.py py2exe

cd dist
hello.exe
Hello World!
```

You can view this tutorial [here](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) as well as more documentation.

Hope this helps.

--lillypad

Comment: py2exe is for windows